# How the kotlin coroutine is implemented under the hood?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Kotlin coroutines are one of the key features in the language. I was curious how they implemented it. So I wrote this kotlin code snippet,

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    someFun(6)  // A suspend fun with single int argument.
}  // Which is converted into a synthetic method with an extra argument of continuation type added at the end.
```

And then compiled it to bytecode and then decompiled it to Java(in Android Studio). I got this,

```
BuildersKt.launch$default(CoroutineScopeKt.CoroutineScope((CoroutineContext)Dispatchers.getIO()), (CoroutineContext)null, (CoroutineStart)null, (Function2)(new Function2((Continuation)null) {
   private CoroutineScope p$;
   Object L$0;
   int label;
            
   @Nullable
   public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object $result) {
      Object var3 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
      CoroutineScope $this$launch;
      switch(this.label) {
      case 0:
         ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
         $this$launch = this.p$;
         MainActivity var10000 = MainActivity.this;
         this.L$0 = $this$launch;
         this.label = 1;
         if (var10000.someFun(6, this) == var3) {
            return var3;
         }
         break;
      case 1:
         $this$launch = (CoroutineScope)this.L$0;
         ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
         break;
      default:
         throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
      }
            
      return Unit.INSTANCE;
   }
            
   @NotNull
   public final Continuation create(@Nullable Object value, @NotNull Continuation completion) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(completion, "completion");
      Function2 var3 = new <anonymous constructor>(completion);
      var3.p$ = (CoroutineScope)value;
      return var3;
   }
            
   public final Object invoke(Object var1, Object var2) {
      return ((<undefinedtype>)this.create(var1, (Continuation)var2)).invokeSuspend(Unit.INSTANCE);
   }
}), 3, (Object)null);
```

Some part of this code I understood. But still some parts are not going into my head.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527848/12357035) answer, a suspend function is split into multiple continuations at each suspension point and then starts executing from the begining by calling `invokeSuspend` continuosly. Each time when `invokeSuspend` is called, it executes the corresponding switch case and then updates the `lable`. So next time when `invokeSuspend` is called, it runs the next case. When <it?> gets call to suspend the function, it stops calling `invokeSuspend` and waits for resume call. Once it gets call to resume, again it continues normally. This is all what I know.

At the first line, Function2 constructor is accepting a null object for Continuation. But why `Function2` class has a single argument constructor? I don't know the implementation of Function2. I searched for its source code, but didn't get it. If possible, I want a link to source code of `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2`.

At the end of case0:, what does `if (var10000.someFun(6, this) == var3) return var3;` actually means.

Who is responsible for calling invokeSuspend after previous call to invokeSuspend is finished. And how it knows when the last case of invokeSuspend is executed?

What does `3, (Object)null` represent in the last argument for `launch$default`

Comment: reading [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-suspend-modifier-under-the-hood-b7ce46af624f) article helped me

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer (I'm no Kotlin expert, I've never used in my work).

> I want a link to source code of kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2.

I found it in Kotlin's stdlib implementation for the JVM.

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/53c523052073b5e39e6cc601ed5278292cfbf4bc/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/functions/Functions.kt#L22-L25

```kotlin
public interface Function2<in P1, in P2, out R> : Function<R> {
    public operator fun invoke(p1: P1, p2: P2): R
}
```

The reason we use this is probably due to the fact that `runBlocking` takes `suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T` as a parameter. `CoroutineScope.()` is an extension method of `CoroutineScope` and it's a `suspend` function which would require a function with 2 arguments when interop-ing with Java. Thus, the `CoroutineScope` instance is passed in as the 1st argument and `Continuation` instance which is the continuation of the coroutine as the 2nd argument.

> At the end of case0:, what does if (var10000.someFun(6, this) == var3) return var3; actually means.

I believe this is to check whether the `someFun` is still suspended.
If it returns the same value as `var3` (which indicates it's suspended), then the current function should also suspend and return `var3`.

A good explanation of this can be found in [The Beginner’s Guide to Kotlin Coroutine Internals](https://doordash.engineering/2021/11/09/the-beginners-guide-to-kotlin-coroutine-internals/).
[Excerpt from the article](https://doordash.engineering/2021/11/09/the-beginners-guide-to-kotlin-coroutine-internals/#:%7E:text=Notice%20this%20variable:%20Object%20var8):

> We can see that a suspend function can either return IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() or the actual result of the function. If the return value is the former case, we know the suspend function we are calling is not ready, and we need to suspend the current function and return.

Back to your questions.

> Who is responsible for calling invokeSuspend after previous call to invokeSuspend is finished. And how it knows when the last case of invokeSuspend is executed?

I believe this would be Kotlin's coroutine scheduler.
I don't have concrete evidence but sniffing around Kotlin's source code, I found this:

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/53c523052073b5e39e6cc601ed5278292cfbf4bc/compiler/ir/backend.common/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/backend/common/lower/AbstractSuspendFunctionsLowering.kt#L169

It seems to be building a function object for the `invokeSuspend` method which makes me think it's going to be called in this layer as opposed to the code generated from the application layer (i.e. your code).

> What does 3, (Object)null represent in the last argument for launch$default

Sorry this one I'm not too sure as I couldn't quite find the source code for `launch$default`.
Let me update the answer if I find anything.