# Handler or Launching a Coroutine Job to do something in the MainThread

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-handler, android-looper, android-handlerthread

I've been wondering about whether it is a better approach to use a [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) ([`Looper.getMainLooper()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper#getMainLooper())) or launch a new Coroutine Job to do small things on the Main Thread, like updating a View.

Handler:

```kotlin
val uiHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

fun foo() {
    uiHandler.post { 
        someView.update()
    }
}
```

Coroutine

```kotlin
fun foo() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        someView.update()
    }
}
```

I really don't know and couldn't find anything related on the Internet, but I'd love to acquire that knowledge.

Comment: why are you _not_ on the main thread ? what are you doing ? perhaps that's relevant to people giving answers

Comment: Gotcha! There are some situations where you can find yourself having to do somethings in a background thread and in the Main Thread in the same method. Or where it is impossible to know in which thread you are in.

Comment: i understand what you're saying and when thread switching is needed, but i wanted to know what _you_ are doing specifically :) are you doing background coroutine operations and then need to do something on the main thread when you're done, or why would _you_ be on the background thread

Comment: Actually my question is for common knowledge - having performance and memory as the main focus. We've gotta consider that `foo()` is not called from a coroutine.

Comment: Did you ever find the right solution?  I am wondering the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both, but I think the common practice is to use coroutines. I don't think handlers are lifecycle aware by default, but coroutines will get cancelled if the view or activity is destroyed. A lot of libraries use suspend functions, so you will have to use coroutines.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223823/20898396), coroutines add tasks to the event loop just like handlers. I was wondering how coroutines work internally and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53526731/20610346) post that uses `mainHandler.post { continuation.resume(value) }` to dispatch a coroutine, so I doubt there will be major differences in performance.

Answer (score 0):

well they both do the same thing.
but if we want to choose we should consider these facts :

- in performing UI update on main thread, **coroutine** is recommended.
  because it has better consistency when coding with coroutines.
- if you want more control in timing stuff like delaying and posting at
  desired time, **Handler** is a better option.
- finally in today's android development, using coroutines and handling
  stuff with it is recommended.